# How to create an object with properties named by an array's elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

While

```js
let Adam = {}; 
{Adam}
// { Adam: {} }
```

the same is not happening for an array of objects:

```js
let Adam = {}; 
let Eva = {}; 
[Adam, Eva].map(man => ({man}))
// [ { man: {} }, { man: {} } ]
```

I would like to have `[{ Adam: {}, Eva: {} }]`. Why is this not the case?

Comment: `{ man }` take the name `man` and the value of `man`. By that point in time it has no idea that the name was originally `Adam` so what you want isn't possible.

Comment: One important thing you seem to misunderstand, is that `[Adam, Eva]` doesn't actually contain `"Adam"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the purpose of this, but you can do this:

```js
let Adam = {}; 
let Eva = {}; 
console.log([{Adam, Eva}])
```

Another alternative is using the function `reduce`.

```js
let Adam = {};
let Eva = {};

var result = [[{Adam}, {Eva}].reduce((a, c) => {
  Object.keys(c).forEach(k => (a[k] = c[k]));
  return a;
}, {})];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it produces an array containing 1 object, instead of an array of objects.

Comment: @frodo2975 see carefully the question's body.

Comment: @frodo2975 from the OP: *I would like to have `[{ Adam: {}, Eva: {} }]`*

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, you're correct, I was interpretting the OP's comment as his desired output instead of what he posted at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do isn't possible programmatically because you're relying on your variable names to create the properties, and in your map function, the variable name is just `man`.

The only way you can create an array like this is by manually specifying each element:

```
const arr = [{Adam}, {Eva}]
```

What you have won't work dynamically, each object would need a `name` or `id` property.

Comment: Mh so how would I go about this with a variable number of objects within that array?

Comment: That's impossible because the way you're doing it now, you're assigning each individual object to a variable, and then relying on those variable names.

Comment: This whole thing is really a bad way to do it, you'd be better off giving each object a "name" or "id" property and using that.

Comment: In the end my goal is to dynamically assign a variable-sized list of objects to a "parent" object whilst preservering their variable name. I thought I could use Object.assign(parentObj, ...) for it to be able to later on call parentObj.childObj on it

Answer (score 0):

```
let Adam = {}; 
let Eva = {};

const arr = [{Adam, Eva}];
```

Comment: Thanks the thing is i need to do it for an array of variable number of objects

Comment: @anthnyprschka check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Because as it is, when you use the **object property shorthand**, it takes the name `man` literally and overwrites that object property name for every iteration of the loop.

Since what you've requested is an array with one object inside, with each of the names nested inside of that object, it would look something like this:

```js
const peopleObject = ["Adam", "Eva"].reduce((accumulatorObject, person) => {
  accumulatorObject[person] = {};
  return accumulatorObject;
}, {});

console.log(peopleObject);
// { Adam: {}, Eva: {} }

const peopleObjectInArray = [peopleObject];
console.log(peopleObjectInArray);
// [ { Adam: {}, Eva: {} } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Adam = {}; 
let Eva = {}; 

let arr = [{}];

arr[0]["Adam"] = Adam;
arr[0]["Eva"] = Eva;

console.log(arr);
```